# how to get key value from json string

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

i have json response like

```
{
    [{
        "name": "abc.html",
        "size": 28135,
        "type": "text/html",
        "delete_url": "XXX",
        "delete_type": "DELETE",
        "attachmentFilePath": "attachment_53b2608e40100/abc.html"
    }, {
        "name": "def.html",
        "size": 10465,
        "type": "text/html",
        "delete_url": "XXXXXX",
        "delete_type": "DELETE",
        "attachmentFilePath": "attachment_53b2608e42bd8/def.html"
    }]
}
```

which i get from `obj.toString()`.

i want to alert each key/value like `name:abc.html` and `size:28135`

Comment: Why do you use `obj.toString` to stringify the object? If you already have an Object, why not iterate over it and output what you need?

Comment: That is invalid JSON. try validating the response in jsonlint.org

Comment: @AlokSwain: It's a perfectly valid JavaScript object.

Comment: @Cerbrus OP should drop `JSON` tag.

Comment: @Cerbrus but this is not valid JSON object

Comment: @AshReva OP is calling it JSON, but this was generated by `obj.toString` and *not* by `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @AshReva, maybe this output comes from Chrome debug. If i remember it right, then this is the way chrome show it to the users...

Comment: Owwait. IT's not even valid JS. Just dumping the code in the console works, assigning it to a variable throws an error, 'cause of the improperly nested array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
obj.forEach(function (d) {    
  alert('name: ' + d.name + ' size: ' + d.size;    
});
```

Hope this helps.